# How works a string variable parsed into an int

Tags: java

I have a project that I didn't made myself and I'm trying to understand how it works.

In a file, I have this code :

```
int nbClasses = PersystConfiguration.getInt(PersystConstantes.NB_CLASSES_DISTRIBUTION);
```

The method `getInt` is just a method to parse in an int. But I don't understand the attribut `NB_CLASSES_DISTRIBUTION` of the class `PersystConstantes`. This class is :

```
String NB_CLASSES_DISTRIBUTION = "persyst.nb.classes.distribution";
```

I really don't understand how this string can be parse into an `int`.

Can somebody help me by telling me how work this kind of variable please ?

Comment: It's very likely fetching a property from somewhere, where `persyst.nb.classes.distribution` is the key and the value is a `String` representing an integer value. You may be able to look for that file (and the value) by grepping for the property key in your resource path. Or it could be some system property set somewhere else. Bottomline, parsing actual `"persyst.nb.classes.distribution"` will throw a `NumberFormatException`, so that's not likely what happens here.

Comment: Why don't you just look inside the `PersystConfiguration.getInt` method and analyze how the String parameter is handled there?

Comment: @Mena You're right, it is a system property. I found a `System.getProperty(key);` where the key is `persyst.nb.classes.distribution`. But where can I found it ? Is it a path or something ? Because I don't find any "distributiion" file :/

Comment: @Erlaunis likely some code actually sets it programmatically: `System.setProperty((String)theKey, (String)theValue)` (although it's not the only way).

Comment: what is `getInt` method ? it really depends on its code.

Answer (score 0):

The function `PersystConfiguration.getInt(String argument1)` returns `int`. Inside the function, its logic must be like, check the argument1 and returns an `int`corresponding/according to that. For e-g  the below function definition is possible.

```
/* Don't Ever Tell anyone I wrote this below code */
    class PersystConfiguration {
        public static Map<String,Integer> Property = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        public static void setProperties() {
            Property.put("persyst.nb.classes.distribution", 0);
            Property.put("persyst.nb.classes.distribution1", 1);
            Property.put("persyst.nb.classes.distribution2", 2);
        }

        public static int getInt(String argument) {
            return Property.get(argument);
        }    
   }
```